# Connect to Kafka installed on HDInsight (Azure)

Tags: java, azure, apache-kafka, azure-hdinsight

I need to connect from external java application to Kafka cluster that started as part of HDinsight on Azure. I have cluster with 3 instances of brokers, 3 ZooKeepers and one ZooKeeper client.

Now my question: how to specify broker connection string. On admin panel I can see 3 brokers like: `xxx-1.yyy.zzz.internal.cloudapp.net`, `xxx-2.yyy.zzz.internal.cloudapp.net` - but these addresses aren't available from external. If I try it then I can see the exception:

> KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
>
> ...
>
> ConfigException: Invalid url in bootstrap.servers:
> xxx-1.yyy.zzz.internal.cloudapp.net

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you're trying to resolve internal azure hostnames, which are not resolvable from the internet.
Also you need to be aware that it is not possible to directly connect to a Kafka instance from the internet.

You need another layer/gateway in between, as you can see here [in this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hacq6.jpg).

As far as I know, you can choose between a [direct connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/connect-on-premises-network) or use another layer in-between, like the [Azure IoT Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-hub/) and a [connector](https://github.com/Azure/toketi-kafka-connect-iothub).

You could choose depending on your use-case which one you want, but be aware that these services are not free and depending on your data size it might add a significant position to your receipt.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect from an on-premises network, you need to set up a site-to-site VPN gateway, see [Connect to Apache Kafka from an on-premises network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-connect-vpn-gateway#on-premises) for details.

If you connect from an individual machine, you need to set up a point-to-site VPN gateway, see [Connect to Apache Kafka with a VPN client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-connect-vpn-gateway#vpnclient) for details.

Answer (score -1):

Check your Kafka configuration and set the property `auto.create.topics.enable`
 to `true`. Restart Kafka and try again.

Comment: It is not relevant answer at all. Topics exists - because from additional VM that is started in the same Azure network I can communicate Kafka instance. My question how to achieve instance from external networks

Answer (score -3):

```
[root@domain bin]# ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list host.domain.net:6667 --topic topic1 --security-protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT 
Test
[2017-04-11 09:07:43,821] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-04-11 09:07:44,022] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-04-11 09:07:44,122] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-04-11 09:07:44,223] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-04-11 09:07:44,323] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-04-11 09:07:44,423] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-04-11 09:07:44,523] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-04-11 09:07:44,624] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 7 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-04-11 09:07:43,821] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-04-11 09:07:44,022] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-04-11 09:07:44,122] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTI
```

It throws this error if you have 3 broker kafka cluster. So whenever you are running a kafka producer and consumer, create a topic with same replication factor with number of brokers.

Command

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test --zookeeper node1:2181,node2:2181,node3:2181 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 3
```

This command is for 3 broker hdinsigt cluster

Comment: Please format your answer and fix the grammar errors.